# Services and Repositories not injected

Tags: java, spring

I am completely desperate with this. These are my first days with spring and I cannot get it working - XMLProfileService is not injected at all, it is still null. I would be very grateful if you could give me some hint. I have no errors in log.

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
        ">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="test.repository"></jpa:repositories>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle11:1521/deviso" />
        <property name="username" value="nbimporttool" />
        <property name="password" value="nbimporttool" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.domain" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**XMLProfileService**

```
@Service
public class XMLProfileService {

    @Inject
    private PropertiesRepository profileDb;


    public void findByNodeName(String nodeName, String password) {
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        new Main2().run();
    }

}
```

**Main2.java**

```
public class Main2 {

    @Autowired
    private XMLProfileService profileService;

    public void run() {
        profileService.findByNodeName("z", "b");
    }

}
```

**pom.xml** (dependencies)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        <!--<exclusions>-->
        <!--<exclusion>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--</exclusion>-->
        <!--</exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**log**

```
13:53:26.337 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'XMLProfileService'
13:53:26.337 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'XMLProfileService'
13:53:26.338 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'XMLProfileService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
13:53:26.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:53:26.340 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'XMLProfileService'
```

Comment: is your `Main2` class managed by Spring as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `Main2` as `new Main2()` of cource Spring know nothing about it.
Create it in spring context. Add this to spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="main2id" class="Main2">
</bean>
```

Then find it. There is some method on `applicationContext` that allow to find bean by id. You need to cast result to your `Main2` class. and invoke your `run` methof after.

Comment: I am sorry for having silly questions, how can create class in Spring context? (and immediatelly after, I buy a book about spring). I have annotated the Main2 class with @Component and make sure it is scanned by component-scan. It does not work ..

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify how to add bean to context,

Comment: Ok, and if the class where the autowiring should be used is a JAX-WS class? It is not managed by Spring but called directly from J2EE server.. Adding this Webservice class in applicationContext does not help.

Comment: I don't understand question. Post it as new one with detailed explanation.